# libuvc_ros not building

Tags: usb, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm trying to use this package thero: http://wiki.ros.org/libuvc_camera

But I get this error when I do catkin_make:

```
    CMake Error at libuvc_ros-master/libuvc_camera/CMakeLists.txt:9 (find_package):
  By not providing "Findlibuvc.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "libuvc", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "libuvc" with any
  of the following names:

    libuvcConfig.cmake
    libuvc-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "libuvc" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "libuvc_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "libuvc"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/paulo/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/paulo/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
Invoking "make cmake_check_build_system" failed
```

Is this my fault or are there missing config files in this package?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/204840/libuvc_ros-not-building/) by [End-Effector](https://answers.ros.org/users/7606/end-effector/) on ROS Answers with karma: 162 on 2015-03-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you run `rosdep` to check that you have all package dependencies installed?

---

Also: that package has been released for Hydro, so if you can, I'd install the binary version (`ros-hydro-libuvc-camera`).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-03-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0